# Trying to connect laravel to mysql but i keep getting an error

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have my laravel app running and i'm trying to connect it to a Mysql database. I'm using XAAMP for this. After getting Apache and Mysql is running (Mysql is running on port 3308). I reconfigured my .env file and database.php file and I've run `php artisan config cache`. However when i try to create a database from my terminal using `create database xxx`, xxx database is created but when i check phpmyadmin on my browser, i can't find the xxx datatbase.
Here's my database.php file:

```
       'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3308'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'test123'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

And here's my .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3308
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=test123
```

Comment: What has laravel to do with the problem? If I understand you correctly, you can create a database via the mysql command line but you cannot see the database in phpmyadmin?

Comment: "_but i keep getting an error_" Can you [edit] your question and paste the error you get?

Comment: I just noticed all the databases i've created are still being created on the 3306 port even after modifying those .env and database.php files

Comment: @Tim Yes, i now see that anytime i create a database, it's been created on the 3306 port and my XAAMP mysql port is 3308. I've modified my .env and database.php files to listen on the 3308 port but it still listens on the 3306 port

Answer (score 0):

Solved it but i had to clear up port 3306 so that XAAMP mysql could use it. Cleared it by ending all mysql tasks under task manager.